# System command execution using Perl

Tags: regex, linux, perl, if-statement

I have a Perl script which runs a perforce command and stores the result in a variable `$command`.

Then it is stored in a file `log.txt`, and by using a regex the relevant data is taken out.

When I run that command alone the following things pop out:

```
  4680 p4exp/v68     PJIANG-015394 25:34:19 IDLE none
  8869 unnamed p4-python       R integration semiconductor-project-trunktip  turbolinuxclient 01:33:52 IDLE none
  8870 unnamed p4-python       R integration remote-trunktip-osxclient 01:33:52
```

The code goes as follows:

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

my $command = qx |p4 monitor show -ale|;

open FH, '>>', "log.txt";
print FH $command;
close FH;

open my $log_fh, '<', '/root/log.txt';
my %stat;
while ($line = <$log_fh>) {
  chomp $line;
  next if not $line =~ /(\d+)\s+/;
  my $killid = $1;
  if ($line =~ /R\s+integration/ and $line =~ /IDLE\s+none$/) {
    my $killid_details = $line;
    $stat{$killid} = $killid_details;
  }
}
close $log_fh;

my $killpro;
foreach my $kill (keys %stat) {
  print "$kill\n";
}
```

The following gets the number 8869 but how to do it without log.txt. Is using an array a better way to do it or hash is fine?

Please correct me as I am still learning.

Comment: There is no need to do two separate regex since you are using the EOL anchor. It can simple be combined into `/R\s+integration.*IDLE\s+none$/` and even though its a single line, I would use `/R[^\S\n]+integration.*IDLE[^\S\n]+none$/` to be sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like your main stumbling block is getting line-by-line input for your loop?

Splitting on newlines should do the trick:

```
my $killid;
my @lines = split("\n", $command); #split on newlines
for my $line (@lines) {
    next if not $line =~ /(\d+)\s+/;
    my $id = $1;
    if ($line =~ /R\s+integration/ and $line =~ /IDLE\s+none$/){
        $killid = $id;
    }
}
```

One caveat: you mentioned an output of 8870, but I'm getting 8869. The regexps you gave are looking for a line with "integration" and "IDLE none", and for your example input that appears to match 8869.

A hash is fine, though if you're using only one key in it (which seems to be the case), you might as well just use a single variable.

Comment: I have edited the above question, you are right about 8869. Thank you your code runs fine and serves the purpose. Also, you mentioned about one reference for hash. Are the different killid's not considered as different keys for hash or what is that one reference. Please can you elaborate. Thank you.

Comment: @deep: The data you show has only one line that contains `R integration` and `IDLE none`. If that is always the case then there is no need to use a hash; a single scalar is sufficient. However if there could sometimes be several such lines then you do need a hash.

Comment: Both of you are spot on, there. Sorry for the oversight on my part.

Answer (score 1):

If you assign the result of a `qx` construct to an array instead of a scalar, then it will be split into lines automatically for you. This code demonstrates.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @lines = qx|p4 monitor show -ale|;

my %stat;
for my $line (@lines) {
  chomp $line;
  next unless $line =~ /(\d+)\s+/;
  my $killid = $1;
  if ($line =~ /R\s+integration/ and $line =~ /IDLE\s+none$/) {
    $stat{$killid} = $line;
  }
}

print "$_\n" for keys %stat;
```